# Disable scrolling of page untill the user has scrolled 300 px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable vertical scrolling of page untill the user has scrolled what would have been 300px if it wasn't disabled, is this possible and how would I go about doing it? Can it be done in jquery?

Comment: You need to do this using javascript, by listening to the scroll() jQuery makes this easy. http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: So say the scrolling was disabled, but the user scrolls with his mouse button down the equivalent of 300px, then scrolling becomes re enabled.So the page doesnt move the first 300px worth of scrolling.

Comment: is pressing down and dragging the mouse wheel and scrolling it the same thing or are they different?

Comment: Dont know how this is unclear i got 2 solid answer that solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question.  Here is one way to accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mLQhT/1/

Note: I did not test this for cross-browser compatibility.

CSS:

```
body { position: relative; }
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function (event) {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(document.body).css('top', Math.min(300, offset));
  });
});
```

Basically, I listened for the scroll event.  On scroll, I set the body's top position to the scroll position, making it look as if the content did not scroll.  I also limit this to a maximum of 300 pixels, so once that point is passed, content will scroll as normal.

---

Edit: Alternate solution

http://jsfiddle.net/mLQhT/3/

In this version, you must wrap your content in a separate div.

CSS:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
}
.content.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var $doc = $(document),
        $content = $doc.find('.content');
    //-- set body size to match content
    $doc.find('body').css({ minHeight: $content.outerHeight() });
    //-- wire up scroll event
    $doc.on('scroll', updateContent);
    function updateContent () {
        var top = $doc.scrollTop();
        if (top < 300) {
            $content.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $content.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }
    //-- run update method on page load
    updateContent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to play with css and javascript scroll event listener.
You play with your main div css positioning

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if( $('.page').css('position')=="fixed" && $(document).scrollTop()>300 ){
        $('.page').css('position','static');
    }else if($('.page').css('position')!="fixed" && $(document).scrollTop()<=300){
        $('.page').css('position','fixed');
    }
})
```

Check this if it helps you:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcA7u/

And with animation :

http://jsfiddle.net/kcA7u/1/

Comment: This was my first thought, but this results in a 300 pixel jump as soon as you scroll to 300 pixels.

Comment: You can use some animation : http://jsfiddle.net/kcA7u/1/

Comment: thanks everyone when I get 6 more rep ill mark everyone that was useful up a point!